# Integrate SlidshowPro Director Class with CDN

Tags: slideshow, cdn

I am currently developing a [website](http://anuragdesign.com/test/mbv/events/wedding_gallery) which uses the [SlideShowPro Director class](http://wiki.slideshowpro.net/SSPdir/API-DirPHP-Getting-Started) to pull images from a SlideShowPro Director installation and serve them to a variety of jQuery slideshows.

The actual images are stored originally stored on my webserver, and the SlideShowPro Director is being used to manage and publish them.

Now, I am wondering whether it is possible to integrate that setup with a CDN. The image URLS which are being provided by the Director Class look as follows:

```
http://mydomain/directorinstallation/p.php?a=WXNnc3ZkJkwpSWNwencsOzEkfHduJzswPiowMTI+MiEiPjE/OzsjKDsnNyMoNDsuOjo3JT4mNzc=&amp;m=1335621206
```

The string provided appears to be a random string, so does the last number. Is there a way to integrate that setup with a CDN? How would I go about it?